# Handle asp.net core localdate model binding exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, nodatime

It was my Intention to return a 400 Status Code from the Server when message payload has an invalid format or data. However, when sending the value xyz123 for a date field the server returns a 500 status code. Exception:

```
NodaTime.Text.UnparsableValueException: The value string does not match the required number from the format string "uuuu". Value being parsed: '^xyz123'. (^ indicates error position.)
   at NodaTime.Text.ParseResult`1.GetValueOrThrow() in C:\Users\jon\Test\Projects\nodatime\build\tzdbupdate\tmp-2.4\nodatime\src\NodaTime\Text\ParseResult.cs:line 81
   at NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet.NodaConverterBase`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 2159
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1032
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 2386
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
```

I would have expected the exception to be catched and placed within the ModelState dictionary. Is there a way to inject this behaviour (i.e. catch exceptions) within JsonInputFormatter or BodyModelBinder in order to add these to the ModelState instead of having them break model binding?

As a workaround I am using an Error Handling Middleware to catch FormatException’s. At this point I however no longer have context information like a JPATH to assist the user or UI-Client.

Possible causes?:

- Bug in NodaTime deserialization, JsonInputFormatter seems to utilize jsonSerializer.Error and prevnt throwing JsonException’s (but FormatException’s are used)
- Bug in asp.net core deserialization, should process FormatException's
- Faulty configuration on my side

Unit Test to reproduce behaviour

```
public class ModelBindingErrorTest
{
    private class ModelBindingErrorStartup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc();
            services.Configure<MvcJsonOptions>(options => options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
            //var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvcCore();
            //mvcBuilder.AddJsonFormatters(jsonSerializerSettings => jsonSerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
            mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(typeof(ModelBindingErrorStartup).Assembly);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var message = "The value string does not match the required number from the format string \"uuuu\". Value being parsed: \'^123xyz\'. (^ indicates error position.)";
        try
        {
            var client = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<ModelBindingErrorStartup>()).CreateClient();
            var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("/MainController/LocalDate", UriKind.Relative), new StringContent("{'Birthday':'123xyz'}", Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json));
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.Equal(message, body);
        }
        catch (UnparsableValueException e)
        {
            Assert.Equal(message, e.Message);
            // The Test Fails Here
            Assert.False(true);
        }
    }
}

[Route("/MainController")]
public class MainController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("LocalDate")]
    public object LocalDate([FromBody]Model model)
    {
        return ModelState["Birthday"].Errors[0].Exception.Message;
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public LocalDate Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Used Packages

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost 2.2.0
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.9.0
- Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1
- NodaTime 2.4.2
- NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet 2.0.0
- Swashbuckle.NodaTime.AspNetCore 2.0.0
- xunit 2.4.1
- xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1

Comment: you might need this https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/testing

Comment: @mvermef thanks for the link, seems interesting for my testing workflow, but i didn't see anything related to serialization? Did I miss something? Fyi the unit test is just to clarify, make an example of the proplem.

Comment: It's not clear what exception a `JsonConverter` *should* throw if it's given invalid data. I'd personally expect `JsonException` to be thrown if the JSON itself is invalid syntactically, but not for the values themselves. The [example of a custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) calls the `Version(string)` constructor which can throw `FormatException` or `ArgumentException`, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I agree and would expect [JsonInputFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L346) - which already sets the [model binder state/error](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L302) - to not re-throw a FormatException. I built a wrapper which does this and might post it as an answer, but this might not be the best solution.

Comment: @Philippe: Right. I'm afraid I don't have a better answer for you :( The Noda Time code demonstrates pretty much everything I know about Json.NET custom serialization :(